# How to bring widget to right of other widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

i want to bring a widget to left,right,top,bottom of other widget !!

in Android we can use RelativeLayout , LinearLayout or ConstraintLayout ...

but in flutter how can i do it ?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the situation, several solutions are possible, but most of the time, you'll be able to get away with it by simply wrapping both widgets in a `Row` or a `Column`.

Comment: im new in flutter can you explain that or show an example please ?!

Comment: Both `Row` and `Column` are widgets that can contain an array of children. These children will be aligned either horizontally or vertically.
Take a look at [this](https://flutter.io/tutorials/layout/#nesting) to see how these widgets works in a broader context.
Keep in mind though that the logic behind the layout construction is quite different from what you'd do in Android, since each Widget has its own constraints rule.